# How can I use corertelephony framework in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I need to include coretelephony framework in my App. I am using jailbreak phone. Is there any sample code available for it.

Please healp 
Thanks
SD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple... just add private framework core telephony in your current project. It's just like we add common framework in XCode. I have done this :)

Comment: Don't forget to `#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>` (or whichever CT header you want) at the top of your file.